# OpenGL - size of the driver in the host memory

Tags: linux, opengl

OpenGL driver creates buffer in the host RAM. When I run some OpenGL application under Linux I can use a **top** command to check how many memory is occupied by a process. Is a OpenGL driver memory usage included in my OpenGL process or I should check some other process, for example Xorg ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not well defined. It may show not up at all (completely in-kernel), be isolated to either your process or the X server, both, or even all three places redundantly.